# Can a flying predator have slit-like pupils?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

In an alien world, much alike earth, exists a theropod-like aerial predator, slightly larger than a lion, which also hunts on land. The creature's eyes occupy around 30% of its face, for hunting both during the day and at night. Now as far as I am aware of, slit shaped pupils are great for hunting at both day and night and provide good depth perception, being common in ambush predators, but it's not as common in animals "far" from the ground, as we see in cats having slit pupils but most panthers having round ones. Would it be possible to have something akin to a slit shape on a flying creature (maybe something like a target shape?) or should I just stick with a round one?

Comment: eyes taking 50% of the face? are you sure? That would be too much even for a manga from the late 80's

Comment: they could but it would offer them no benefit, if anything it would be a determent. slit like pupils are for detecting movement in a horizontal plane, the exact opposite of what a flying creature needs.

Comment: @john well, don't take it in an absolute sense, otherwise you risk reaching the conclusion [goats are natural-born airborne predators](https://www.google.com/search?q=goat+pupil) ;p

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I don't get the joke.

Comment: @John he meant that by looking solely at the pupil shape, if you go by the principle that, for example, all animals with slit pupils are ambush predators, then a goat's eyes would indicate its an aerial hunter, since it would give them a wide vertical range of view (assuming it works the opposite way of an upwards slit)

Comment: To add to the @ProjectApex's explanation, in real terms: [Why Do Goats Have Such Weird Eyes?](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/67114/why-do-goats-have-such-weird-eyes). TL;DR: slit pupil give an advantage on the image sharpness, goat's horizontal slit allows them to use this advantage while grazing (lowered head will make the pupil vertical)

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi their eyes are also great at providing them with an ample field of view, which is also why their pupil shape is common in prey animals, with some having nearly 360 degree view, at the cost of poor telescopic view

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi goat eyes are rectangular pupils not slit eyes they are are very different structures, there is no reason one would predict the other. Eyes are actually very good predictors of an animals behavior.

Comment: @John you are being gratuitously pedantic. This comment was to add my little bit of pedantry ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skimmers, which are real-life birds, have slit pupils.

Given their rarity, the evolutionary advantage of slit pupils seems pretty minor.  The good news is that you can give your flying predator whatever eye type you like.

Having an aerial predator bigger than a lion may be more of an issue, don't sweat the small stuff...!

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the size issue when it comes to flying creatures in earth like conditions, but as I was basing it on a real giraffe sized flying creature, I'd say it's not that big an issue. Though I was more concerned about the most effective kind of pupil since it relies a lot on vision while flying, but one thing I'll say, this bird's eyes are almost what I want, I'm just worried about this being due to their small size